# QPushButton is drawn like a white rectangle on MacOS

Tags: macos, qt

I created a simple dialog in Qt and added two pushbuttons from the palette.

On windows they look Ok:

[image]

But on Mac the second button is not drawn:

[image]

What could be the reason?

Buttons markup is:

```
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="okButton">
    <property name="text">
     <string>OK</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Cancel</string>
    </property>
    <property name="autoDefault">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

Comment: I didn't override any drawing handlers, only clicked() slot which calls close()

Comment: What version of Qt are you using ? On what version of macOS ?

Comment: Also: In case you are using macOs in a Virtual Machine, these kind glitches sometimes happen

Comment: Qt 5.1; Latest MacOS, real machine ( customer )